# Derive from Unchecked_Union

Tags: ada, gnat

I declare a union type like this:

```
type Access_Kind is (Named, Indexed);
type Array_Type is array (0 .. 1) of Integer;

type Record_Type (Kind : Access_Kind := Access_Kind'First) is record
   case Kind is
      when Named =>
         X, Y : Integer;
      when Indexed =>
         S : Array_Type;
   end case;
end record;
pragma Unchecked_Union (Record_Type);
pragma Convention (C_Pass_By_Copy, Record_Type);

function Create (X, Y : Integer) return Record_Type;
```

Now when I try to create a derived type:

```
type Integer2 is new Record_Type;
```

GNAT gives me the following warning:

```
warning: in instantiation at line [pragma Convention...]
warning: variant record has no direct equivalent in C
warning: use of convention for type "Integer2" is dubious
```

So it looks like the pragma Convention is applied to the derived type, but Unchecked_Union is not. I cannot apply it to the derived type again because `Record_Type` already has primitive operations defined (`Integer2` is defined in another package).

Is this correct behavior or a GNAT bug? How can I correctly derive from Unchecked_Union types so that the new type inherits the Unchecked_Union pragma?

GNAT Version: GNAT GPL 2012 (20120509).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to declare the operations of `Record_Type` in a nested package, say `Ops`, so that they aren't primitive:

```
package Union is

   type Access_Kind is (Named, Indexed);
   type Array_Type is array (0 .. 1) of Integer;

   type Record_Type (Kind : Access_Kind := Access_Kind'First) is record
      case Kind is
         when Named =>
            X, Y : Integer;
         when Indexed =>
            S : Array_Type;
      end case;
   end record;
   pragma Unchecked_Union (Record_Type);
   pragma Convention (C_Pass_By_Copy, Record_Type);

   --  If P was declared immediately within Union, it would be
   --  primitive, and it wouldn't be possible to declare
   --  representation aspects for Integer2.
   package Ops is
      procedure P (R : Record_Type) is null;
      --  "is null" only so that I can use -gnatR without needing a
      --  body.
   end Ops;

   type Integer2 is new Record_Type;
   pragma Unchecked_Union (Integer2);
   pragma Convention (C_Pass_By_Copy, Integer2);

end Union;
```

Using `-gnatR` to display the chosen representation, I get

```
$ gnatmake -c -u -f -gnatwa union.ads -gnatR
gcc -c -gnatwa -gnatR -gnat05 union.ads

Representation information for unit Union (spec)
------------------------------------------------

for Array_Type'Size use 64;
for Array_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Array_Type'Component_Size use 32;

for Record_Type'Size use 64;
for Record_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Record_Type use record
   Kind at ?? range  0 ..  -1;
   X    at  0 range  0 .. 31;
   Y    at  4 range  0 .. 31;
   S    at  0 range  0 .. 63;
end record;

for Integer2'Size use 64;
for Integer2'Alignment use 4;
for Integer2 use record
   Kind at ?? range  0 ..  -1;
   X    at  0 range  0 .. 31;
   Y    at  4 range  0 .. 31;
   S    at  0 range  0 .. 63;
end record;
```

That said, I think GNAT's behaviour is wrong.

[ARM 13.1(0.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-1.html#p0.1) says that there are *representational* and *operational* aspects, and [(1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-1.html#p1) defines the representational aspects. [(10)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-1.html#p10) is why we need to avoid primitive operations. [(15)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-1.html#p15) says that representational aspects are inherited by derived types; but [(15.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-1.html#p15.1) says that operational aspects are **not**, "unless specified" for the specific aspect. I guess that "specified" means "in the ARM for language-defined aspects, or by the vendor for vendor-defined aspects".

[B3.3(3.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-3.html#p3.1) states that `Unchecked_Union` is a representation aspect. It should therefore be inherited.

[B3.1(0.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-1.html#p0.1) states that interfacing aspects, including `Convention`, are representation aspects. `C_Pass_By_Copy` should therefore be inherited.

I'll work up a bug report.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed analysis. As I actually *want* all operations of the base type to be primitive, moving them to a nested package isn't really a solution; seems like I need to declare the operations for all derived types.

Comment: +1 for chasing this down; checking an older version, it looks like a regression.

Comment: trashgod, which version? I've tried GNAT GPL 2011, 2012, GCC 4.6.0, 4.7.0, 4.8.0 & all fail.

Comment: D'oh, my error; I overlooked the pragmas you added to `Integer2`; my [update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663857/230513) looks at the unadorned declaration. Using your package, I get the same result going back to 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

In Ada 2012, [`pragma Unchecked_Union`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-J-15-6.html) is obsolescent, and you can now specify aspect [`Unchecked_Union`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-3.html). In either case, as discussed in [*Rationale for Ada 2005: 6.4 Pragmas and Restrictions*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-6-4.html), the warning is a reminder that unchecked union types were "introduced in Ada 2005 for the sole purpose of interfacing to C programs and not for living dangerously." A type derived from `Record_Type` is not forbidden; it's just a bad idea, as it propagates the opportunity for *erroneous execution*, as shown in the [*Notes*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-3.html) section. Instead, encapsulate the union in the body of your binding and derive from your higher level type.

Addendum: Checking an older versions for reference,

```
GNAT 4.6
Copyright 1996-2010, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
Representation information for unit Unchecked (body)
----------------------------------------------------

for Array_Type'Size use 64;
for Array_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Array_Type'Component_Size use 32;

for Record_Type'Size use 64;
for Record_Type'Alignment use 4;
for Record_Type use record
   Kind at ?? range  0 ..  -1;
   X    at  0 range  0 .. 31;
   Y    at  4 range  0 .. 31;
   S    at  0 range  0 .. 63;
end record;

for Integer2'Size use 96;
for Integer2'Alignment use 4;
for Integer2 use record
   Kind at 0 range  0 ..  7;
   X    at 4 range  0 .. 31;
   Y    at 8 range  0 .. 31;
   S    at 4 range  0 .. 63;
end record;
```

Comment: While your statements are correct, this doesn't answer my question. Besides the warning, I have other proof that the derived type isn't an Unchecked_Union (minimal type size includes discriminant size), so I still want to know why this isn't the case and how I can fix this. Btw, the mentioned erroneous execution isn't possible in this case as both variants contain the same type and therefore cannot be used for an unchecked conversion.

Comment: Right, the derived type `Integer2` _has_ a discriminant; it's an Ada variant record that has no direct equivalent in C; moreover, `C_Pass_By_Copy` doesn't make sense for parameters having that type. Sorry if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: `C_Pass_By_Copy` would make sense if `Unchecked_Union` was inherited like `C_Pass_By_Copy` is. Both are representation pragmas, so it doesn't make sense that one is inherited and the other isn't. That's what I am wondering about.

Comment: While `Record_Type` has a discriminant of size 0, `Integer2` has space for a discriminant; the default discriminant inherited from `Record_Type` can be examined, but it cannot be altered.

Comment: Also, note that "A subtype of an unchecked union type is defined to be an _unchecked union subtype_."